# Angular.js: UI not updating when variable changes

Tags: javascript, angularjs, scope

I'm starting lo learn about Angular.js and I have created this controller for my app:

```
    angular.module('appName',[]).controller('mainController', [ function() {
        var self = this;
        self.appTitle = "List of done and not done things";
        self.readStatus = "readed";
        self.changeReadStatus = function() {
            readStatus = "not readed";
        };
        self.generalReadStatus = "Today I have " + self.readStatus + " this list.";
    }]);
```

The markup looks like this:

```
<div ng-controller="mainController as ctrl">
    <h1 ng-bind="ctrl.generalReadStatus"><h1>
    <button ng-click="ctrl.changeReadStatus()">Change Status</button>
</div>
```

The browser ouputs:

[image]

In the html mark-up I use `ng-click="ctrl.changeReadStatus()"` to call the function and change the content. Now, I know that the value changes, but the UI (html code) is not updating. Why?

Comment: can you show the template? besides, in the function you are not changing `self`'s state

Comment: @Dinesh I updated the question and also I put an answer with the solution that I was looking for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that the controller's generalReadStatus has already been evaluated and is not being updated when the dependent variable changes. I imagine that in your template you are doing something to the effect of:

```
<p>{{ctrl.generalReadStatus}}</p>
```

Try something like this instead:

```
<p>Today I have  {{ctrl.readStatus}} this List.</p>
```

Comment: This solved the problem! It looks like `ng-bin` does not work the same way that `{{}}`

Answer (score 1):

Try changing to

```
self.changeReadStatus = function() {
        self.readStatus = "not readed";
    };
```

Answer (score 0):

You're not binding this object to controller. Use

```
self.changeReadStatus = function() {
       self.readStatus = "not readed";
};
```

instead

```
self.changeReadStatus = function() {
       readStatus = "not readed";
};
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to modify the variable **on the controller**:

```
self.readStatus = "readed";
self.changeReadStatus = function() {
    self.readStatus = "not readed";
};
```

Answer (score 0):

I found that if I change the `mark-up`to this

```
<h1 ng-bind="ctrl.viewStatus(ctrl.currentViewStatus)"></h1>

<button ng-click="ctrl.changeStatus()">CHANGE VIEW STATUS</button>
```

and the controller to this

```
    angular.module('noteApp', []).controller('mainCtrl', [
        function() {
            var self = this;

            self.currentViewStatus = "not viewed";

            self.changeStatus = function() {
                self.currentViewStatus = "already viewed";
            }

            self.viewStatus = function(status) {
                return "The list has been " + status;
            }

        }]);
```

The `html`updates when I click the `button`